# gRPC error about missing an "Unimplemented" server method

Tags: go, grpc

**this my proto file:**

```html
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = ".;pb";

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply); // hello
}

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

**

```css
package main

import (
    "awesomeProject/grpc_test/proto"
    "context"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "net"
)


type Server struct {}

func (s *Server) SayHello(ctx context.Context, request *pb.HelloRequest) (*pb.HelloReply, error) {
    return &pb.HelloReply{
        Message: "hello" + request.Name,
    }, nil
}

func main() {
    g := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterGreeterServer(g, &Server{})

    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:8080")
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to listen: " + err.Error() )
    }

    err = g.Serve(lis)
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to start grpc: " + err.Error())
    }
}
```

and i got an error:

`cannot use &Server{} (type *Server) as type pb.GreeterServer in argument to pb.RegisterGreeterServer:*Server does not implement pb.GreeterServer (missing pb.mustEmbedUnimplementedGreeterServer method)`

how to solve it?

Comment: What did you use to generate the Go code from the proto file? It looks like you are using a toolkit that requires you to embed a type into your server struct.

Comment: some implementation issue. have you checkout https://buf.build/ ?
it help setting up and maintaining gRPC services in Go.

Comment: @BurakSerdar that happens with the official [protoc-gen-go-grpc](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/) toolkit when invoked as `protoc --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=.`. It does not happen (yet) when invoked via a plugin: `protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:.`

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in this [README](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc/README.md) ([this issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/2318) and [this issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/3669) provide a lot, perhaps too much!, more info).

The solution will be to edit your `struct` definition (as the error suggests) to:

```golang
type Server struct {
    proto.UnimplementedGreeterServer
}
```

You might also want to take a look at the [quickstart](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/). Your service appears to be derived from this and you will note that `main.go` (`/examples/helloworld/greeter_server/main.go` in [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/archive/v1.41.0.zip)) includes a similar `struct` definition.

Adding `proto.UnimplementedGreeterServer` provides a default implementation for all of the services (part of the generated code); for example:

```
func (UnimplementedGreeterServer) SayHello(context.Context, *HelloRequest) (*HelloReply, error) {
    return nil, status.Errorf(codes.Unimplemented, "method SayHello not implemented")
}
```

Including `UnimplementedGreeterServer` within the structure means that if you add a new service to the `proto` file and then recompile your application it will compile without error AND return an unimplemented error should a client attempt to call the new service. The issues referenced earlier include a lot of discussion around why this method was selected.